# Is there a room for "another SUSY" to reduce extra dimensions?

Tags: string-theory, group-theory, supersymmetry, spacetime-dimensions, compactification

I've heard that supersymmetry already dropped dimensions count in String theories from 26 to 10 (11 - after Witten).

So, is there any space left in the rest of the math to introduce some "another SUSY" (or similar) to drop now from 11 to may be even 4 - ?..

I do not know much else about SUSY, but I bet I won't be the only one in line for a **detailed** answer, since I haven't seen such talks anywhere.

I only heard once [from Clifford V. Johnson](https://youtu.be/3KC32Vymo0Q?t=1602) that this might be possible; but without any further directions.

Comment: There is a string theory like this that's almost what one would want. It has four dimensions but two are space and two are time.

Comment: They're pretty old but maybe https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9207062 contains enough review.